# Is $t\sin\left(\frac1t\right)$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing, uniform-continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to (0,1)$, $f=t\sin\left(\frac1t\right)$. I think this function is uniformly continuous, but I don't see how to prove this formally. I can observe that if $s,t\in (0,1)$ and $|s-t|<\delta$, then the smaller $\delta$ we take, the smaller the quantity $$\left|t\sin\left(\frac1t\right)-s\sin\left(\frac1s\right)\right|\mbox{  (*)}$$ becomes. So we can take any $\varepsilon>0$ and any $s,t$, such that (*) is less than $\varepsilon$, and there will necessarily be a $\delta>0$ such that $|s-t|<\delta$.

I would appreciate some suggestions on what approach to take.

Comment: What is the domain of this function?

Comment: @zhw. Sorry, it's $(0,1)$, edited.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is differentiable, then it must necessarily be continuous.

Now,

$$\frac{df}{dt} = -\frac{1}{t}\cos{\frac{1}{t}} + \cos{\frac{1}{t}}$$

As you can see, the derivative is defined at all points except at $t=0$.

So for $t=0$, we will have to check the limit.

The limit is easy to calculate (by applying the squeeze theorem) and comes out to be

$$t\sin{\frac{1}{t}} = 0$$

when $t$ tends to $0$.

Hence proved.

Comment: It's not made clear here how this shows *uniform* continuity. (I'll acknowledge this is easy, but seems at least a word would be good at this level.)

Comment: So why is $f$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1)?$

Comment: I guess we can use compactness of $[0,1]$. Since $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$, it is continuous on $(0,1)$. But it is also continuous on $[0,1]$. Thus $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, and so it is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.